# Display content reference with another content

Tags: 7, views, entities

I just starting using Drupal and I have few question.

Currently I have two Content Types: `Project` and `Task`.

Project's field is:

- Project title
- Body
- Date

Task's field is:

- Task title
- Body
- Project (field_project), Entity reference

And I create a view to display List of project.

The problem is, How to display List of task when a project detail is viewed

Comment: Have you read the basic Views documentation? It is on https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a view with title list in Task content type, in this create a Contextual filters with field_project. Take the filter value from url arguments.

Comment: Contextual filters. Thanks, I also just read it. So I create a view, and display it on block